# Friend Syntax for Ptr-to-member template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, friend, pointer-to-member

Okay, so I believe this is a pure c++ mucky syntax question.

I have a class defined with a ptr-to-member as one of its template parameters:

```
template <class T, T *T::*hook> class My_list {
```

I have another simple class that is a friend of this class. Usually, I would write:

```
class My_friend_class {
    template <class, class> friend class My_list;
};
```

...but, because the second template parameter isn't that free...how do I state the friendship?

Thanks!

Comment: In the same way, `template <class T, T * T::*>`?

Comment: oh wow. Right you are. I thought I tried that, but I tried `template <class T, T *T::*hook> friend class My_list<T, hook>;` . Turns out leaving out the last template does the trick. Thanks!

Comment: OK, but be careful, there's a difference between a single friend inside a template, and a templated family of friends... and even then the template-friend syntax requires care.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a better question is "Why?" rather than "How?"

Exactly what are you trying to achieve?  When your C++ code becomes complex and ugly, it is often a warning that you are approaching a problem wrongly.